# Creating paths in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c

How can can I create a path in Xcode 5 that resembles a half circle. I was able to make the code that goes in the .m file, but I do not know what to do in the .h file for the code that is in the .m file. I followed a tutorial and this is the code I came out with in the .m file.

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                     [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: please show an example of what you have tried.

Comment: follow the tutorial... if it is not clear, find another one

Comment: This needs to be UIView subclass. Do you know how to declare it a UIView subclass in the .h file? Are you doing that? Do you know how to get an instance of this UIView subclass into your interface?

Comment: No, is that where you create a new objective-c file and make the class UIView--because i tried that but i was not able to find the option UIView.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch04.html#_interface_and_implementation

Comment: By the way, I tried your code and it does do something (it draws an ellipse). So the first thing to do is convince yourself of that. Then you can start modifying it so that it draws what _you_ want.

Comment: I just answered that question.

Comment: How were you able to make the code work?

Comment: I pasted it into the .m file of a UIView subclass and put the UIView subclass into the interface so I could see what it looked like when I ran the project.

Comment: I've already pointed you to my book. It's free to read online. Why not take some time and learn before you thrash around like this?

Comment: Do not delete question and replace by another. If you want to ask another question ask another question.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to make a view that draws itself as half a circle is to make a view that draws itself as a circle but the view is only half the width of the circle. That way, what is drawn outside the view (the other half of the circle) is not shown.

Comment: is there anything i need to do in the .h file for this code to make the ellipse?

Comment: No as long as the .h file declares that this is a UIView subclass, as I pointed you to earlier.